# Object looping on different type of data

Tags: java

I am new to Java.
I have a List of objects, that contains both strings and arrays.

List e.g. [["alfa","beta",["gamma","pi"], "foo"], ["alfa","beta",["gamma","pi"], "foo"]] where one object is ["alfa","beta",["gamma","pi"], "foo"]

I want to iterate like: "alfa" "beta" ["gamma", "pi"] "foo" ---- end----- –

How should I do that?

Comment: Do you start with a list, or have a string you are trying to put into a list? (I ask because you mentioned "," as a separator)

Comment: What do you mean "',' as a separator" ? Could you show us what you did so far?

Comment: You claim to have "List of objects" which suggests something like List<Object>, but later you describe that "*if I use "," as a separator*" which suggests you have String *representing* list of objects. These are not the same. Please clarify your post.

Comment: I got it, will clarify it in a minute.

Comment: I edited the question, thanks for the clarification.

List<Object> e.g. [["alfa","beta",["gamma","pi"], "foo"], ["alfa","beta",["gamma","pi"], "foo"]]
where one object is  ["alfa","beta",["gamma","pi"], "foo"]
I want to iterate like:
"alfa"
"beta"
["gamma", "pi"]
 "foo"
 ---- end-----

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly try something like

```
for (Object object : listName) {
        if(object.getClass() == String.class){
            //do whatever string operations you want
        } else{
            if(object.getClass() == String[].class){
                //do whatever string array operations you want
            }
        }
    }
```